# Python tarfile error - gzip module not available

Tags: python, gzip, tarfile

I have the following code

```
import tarfile

for archive in archives:
    tar = tarfile.open(archive, "r:gz")
    tar.extractall()
    tar.close()
```

where `archives` is list of files with `.tar.gz` extension. Although it crashes while trying to open tar.gz file with `tarfile.CompressionError: gzip module is not available`. It is interesting, because module gzip.py is located in `/usr/lib/python2.6`.

When I try command `file <name_of_archive>` it returns: `<name_of_archive>: gzip compressed data, from Unix.`

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: The existence of the gzip.py is irrelevant - it relies on the zlib-module, which is a dynamically loaded python extension library which should be compiled into your interpreter. Unless your compiled it yourself, without support for it. So the question is: what OS, and where did python come from?

Comment: In the end this should be platform-independent script (Windows 7,8, Debian, CentOS), but right now I'm testing this on Debian 7.6. And I downloaded python from python.org if that is what you mean.

Comment: But is the Python a standard-installed python? What happens if you do "import zlib"? Can you install additional python-packages (Debian and other distros ofter rip apart the standard python installer into various bits of pieces for the sake of their own packaging rules)

Comment: Yes, it is standard-installed. Importing zlib fails for there is no such module. And I'm sorry, but I don't know how to install additional packages.

Comment: I don't find anything towards this - you should look into your package-manager of choice and search for something python/zlib related. That might solve the problem.